# How to solve Mac Apple Store repeatedly prompting for Apple ID and password?

Tags: apple-id, password, mac-appstore

I've got a shared Mac from my company. The Mac was previously associated with another Apple ID. I logged out and I logged in with my Apple ID.

I urgently need to be able to develop for iOS 13, and for this reason, I need to update XCode to the latest version. When I open the Apple Store it starts prompting for Apple ID and password, and the Apple ID field is automatically filled with the previous Apple ID, the one I signed out. If I type my Apple ID and my password in place of that, after 30 seconds it prompts again for the same information, in the same way.

I've tried a lot of tricks, all the ones that came out when you google for this problem. But none of them helped. I tried signing out, restarting, enabling two factors authentication, removing the password prompt in the settings, but nothing made any difference.

The only thing I didn't try was putting a valid credit card in the payment settings of my Apple ID. The credit card I had inserted time ago expired, and I don't want to insert any credit card info on a shared computer. Furthermore, I just want to update a free app and I don't think there are no alternatives.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The version of Xcode - & everything else that was already on the Mac when you got it, including the OS itself - doesn't strictly belong to you. It belongs to the Apple ID that originally 'purchased' it, even if that purchase was free.
App & OS ownership is not transferrable.

Unless your company runs an MDM solution allowing it to properly manage company-purchased apps, then the simplest solution is to wipe the entire machine & start afresh. That way everything then 'belongs' to you.

The Mac also needs to be released from the Find My & entire iCloud structure too.

See [Apple KB - What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065) for a comprehensive guide.

As it's a corporate Mac, you'd be best to speak to your IT department before going at this single-handed, as it will likely require the compliance of the previous user.